# Chrome Extension running in background when the popup is not in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to create a Chrome Extension for starters. I'm a bit stuck because I do not know how to make my extension run in the background.

I have researched an answer for my issue but I haven't identified a suitable solution.

The logic of my extension is in AngularJS controller files.
I do not know how to create the background.js file to communicate with my AngularJS controller files or even if it's necessary to have one.

I would like the extension logic to run even when the popup does not appear in view (e.g. modHeaders app).

The manifest file is:

```
    "manifest_version": 2,   
    "name": "Chrono",   
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Reminder",   
    "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "images/timerIcon.png",
            "default_popup": "index.html",
            "default_title": "ChronoBip"   
},   
    "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false   
},   
    "permissions": [
            "background",
            "tabs"   ] 
    }
```

If you need more info, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running separate `.js` file(background.js), try running your controller JS file as your background scripts. See if it works.

Here I placed my controller(myAppCtrl.js) file in background.

```
"manifest_version": 2,   
    "name": "Chrono",   
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Reminder",   
    "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "images/timerIcon.png",
            "default_popup": "index.html",
            "default_title": "ChronoBip"   
},   
    "background": {
            "scripts": ["app/controllers/myAppCtrl.js"],
            "persistent": false   
},   
    "permissions": [
            "background",
            "tabs"   ] 
    }
```

Comment: @Roxana Bitoleanu if it doesnt work,let me know. I will guide you in more better way.

Comment: I tried this solution too, but it didn't work.
I included before the controllers everything the app requires like angular, jquery, bootstrap etc. and it still does not work. 
If you have more ideas/solutions, please guide me. Thank you